# How to replace text in R using regular expression?

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a vector of strings that looks something like this: `c("abc@40gmail.com", "xyz@50gmail.com")`. For some reason, there are random/different digits after the `@` and I'm trying to remove them. Using regular expression, how can I tell R to remove or replace the digits that come after `"@"`, so I end up with `c("abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com")`. I don't know much about Regex, so I'd really really appreciate if someone can provide not just the code, but also a brief explanation of the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas has is that a dupe? From now on every text replacement question is a dupe of `gsub("e", "", x)`? The regex in the "dupe" is of exact match type, while in this question, it is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  Positive lookbehind or `\K`

```
sub("(?<=@)\\d+", "", x, perl=T)
```

`\\d+` matches one or more digits characters. So `(?<=@)` forces the regex engine to look immediate after to the `@` symbol and then make it to match the following one or more digit characters. Since lookarounds belong to the PCRE family, you need to enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

**OR**

```
sub("@\\K\\d+", "", x, perl=T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any reason why you wouldn't just use the simpler `sub("@\\d+", "@", x)`?

Comment: @hsl because it's already mentioned. We could write atleast two answers for a single regex based question. :-) That's the beauty of regex.

Answer (score 3):

One option is

```
x <- c("abc@40gmail.com", "xyz@50gmail.com")
sub("@\\d+", "@", x)
## [1] "abc@gmail.com" "xyz@gmail.com"
```

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, ok, nvm then.